# RBS on SharePoint 2013 file size limit

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server-2012, rbs

I read the MSDN article (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) where it says that enabling FILESTREAM storage will allow to overcome the limitation of 2GB file sizes. If I would enable **Remote Blob Storage** on SharePoint 2013 + SQL 2012, would it mean that the users will be able to uploaded files to document libraries without any size limitations? Or is there a limit even with RBS enabled? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There always will be a maximum upload size for each web application, maximum timeout time in IIS for for each IIS site and a lot of other soft limits (thresholds, can be changed), but hard limits (boundaries) can never be changed.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.15%29.aspx states:

> Boundaries are absolute limits that cannot be exceeded by design. It is important to understand these limits to ensure that you do not make incorrect assumptions when you design your farm.
>
> An example of a boundary is the 2 GB document size limit; **you cannot configure SharePoint Server 2013 to store documents that are larger than 2 GB**. This is a **built-in absolute value**, and **cannot be exceeded by design**.

Also https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628583.aspx says:

> RBS **does not increase the storage limits of content databases**. All limitations still apply to RBS-enabled content databases. RBS is intended to lower storage costs by allowing you to store large read-intensive BLOBs on less expensive drives.

Comment: Side-note: while `RBS does not increase the storage limits of content databases`, it allows to partially bypass SQL Express DB size limit, because content stored in RBS doesn't count against DB size. Can't find exact link to back this up, but I did it myself once and it worked.

Comment: Good point, thanks. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895334.aspx#SQLServerExpress: **SQL Server Express supports FILESTREAM. The 10-GB database size limit does not include the FILESTREAM data container.**